# Pull tweet upon provided tweet URL

Tags: php, drupal, twitter

I am trying to develop a CCK module, this module basically provides a field that handles a tweet URL.
On node save, Drupal will pull this tweet's text depending on the tweet URL i submitted and display it formatted.

Does Twitter API provide any function that handles this type of requests ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i figured a way out to integrate this with CCK in Drupal
http://batayneh.me/post/how-pull-tweet-pasting-its-url-drupal-cck

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get the contents of a tweet.

http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/show/:id